# How many votes were cast in the 2014 EU elections?

Tags: european-union

I read on the [European Pirate Party Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Pirate_Party#European_2014_elections_results) that they received 868 069 votes.  I would like to compare this figure with the total votes cast for all parties.  The [EU Parliament Results](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/elections2014-results/en/turnout.html) only shows the turnout in terms of percentages.

Answer (score 2):

The total turnout for the 2014 EU election of was [42.54%](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/elections2014-results/en/election-results-2014.html).
The total population of the EU in 2014 is [507,416,607](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/tgm/table.do?tab=table&language=en&pcode=tps00001&tableSelection=1&footnotes=yes&labeling=labels&plugin=1) (estimated provisional)
I wasn't able to find out an breakdown of ages groups which separated the ages at exactly voting age - so the best estimate I can give is [15%](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/tgm/table.do?tab=table&init=1&language=en&pcode=tps00010&plugin=1) which are under 14 and of the 15-24 age group (11%) I'll just add 5% so we get a nice even number of 20% of Europeans who are not eligible to vote due to age restrictions.

That leaves about 400.000.000 European (a number also seen on the [official elections page](http://www.elections2014.eu/en/news-room/content/20140428STO45334/html/Get-inspired-become-a-voter)) who could have voted - with the turnout of 42.54% that comes out as **170,160,000**.

Comment: That's some good extrapolation, but I'd really like to know the actual number of votes cast, not the number of people who were potentially eligible to vote.

Answer (score 2):

I think I just found what you were looking for :

Regitered voters : 396.104.240
Voters : 168.818.151
Turnout : 42,61%
Valid votes : 163.551.013

[Source: Page 40 of this review](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/pdf/elections_results/review.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The European Pirate Party got no votes - the national parties did. The only "successful" one would be the German Pirate Party, specifically [424,510](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirate_Party_Germany#2014_European_Parliament_election) (1.45%). They got one MEP ([Julia Reda](https://juliareda.eu/en/)). EU Parliament members are voted separately for each state.

A few other national pirate parties also participated as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Pirate_Party#European_2014_elections_results). You can find a table of votes and the relevant percentages.